# create header using package fancyhdr - Mirror Page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How to create header using package `fancyhdr` like the below format? It is like mirror page.

```
LO                           PN    |    PN                           RE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

LO - Left ODD

PN - Pagenumber

RE - RightEven

I want a output in latex and Can anyone send example for this code?

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Comment: Can anyone send example for this code?
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

Comment: What do you mean "send example for this code"?

Answer (score 2):

Did you give up on the [fancyhdr manual](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) before page 7?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can anyone send example for this code?
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}